# How to disable swiper `next` button

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VrWt_lMrJE4). Now I would like to use this for a wizard. I've divided a form into multiple steps. Now because of this, the next button should only be enabled if you have a valid form. I cannot find in the documentation how to do this. My current swiper config looks like this

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: false,

    // Navigation arrows
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',

    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    allowSwipeToPrev: false,
    allowSwipeToNext: false,
});
```

Any suggestions how to enable/disable the next button?

Comment: Add the `swiper-button-disabled` class to the `.swiper-button-next` element.

Comment: thanks, that works!!